# Access a global variable from within a ClientFunction

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, e2e-testing, end-to-end, testcafe

I would like to know if it's possible to access a variable from within a ClientFunction, or whether I should always pass required arguments into it?

I'm using TestCafe's ClientFunction to make an HTTP request (creating a new user). We have multiple environments, and so I don't want to hardcode a URL into the request.

If I pass in the desired URL to the function that, then the request completes... but I received an error when trying to access a `createUserUrl` variable.

```
import createUserUrl from '../config.js'.createUserUrl;

const createUserRequest = ClientFunction(userDetails => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', createUserUrl, true);

    xhr.onload = function() {
      resolve(xhr.responseText);
    };

    // Set headers:
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(userDetails));
  });
});
```

Resulting in `ReferenceError: reqUrl is not defined`.

Otherwise, this option works

```
const createUserRequest = ClientFunction(reqUrl, userDetails => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', reqUrl, true);

    xhr.onload = function() {
      resolve(xhr.responseText);
    };

    // Set headers:
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(userDetails));
  });
});
```

Is the 2nd option the preferred route to go, or is there a way to access a variable from within the ClientFunction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client Functions have [certain limitations](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#limitations) and cannot access variables defined in the outer scope. I also suggest you consider passing the necessary variables through the Client Function's [`options.dependencies`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#optionsdependencies) object:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const articleHeader = Selector('#article-header');

const getArticleHeaderHTML = ClientFunction(() => articleHeader().innerHTML, {
     dependencies: { articleHeader }
});
```